# Limiting the number of pagination pages

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have one page where I echo 10 items from MySql DB and has pagination for next page. The problem is that there are 1000+ rows in database.. so you can guess how many pages are in pagination links. How can I limit their numbers for example to show

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... N
```

when user change to page 2

```
2 3 4 5 6 ... N
```

and so on?

Or something else.. the main goal is just to hide every single page number.

```
 <?php
     if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
     $start_from = ($page-1) * 10;
     $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM images t order by randorder ASC LIMIT $start_from, 10");
     $result->execute();

     for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
     {                                      
            echo 'echo data';
     }

    echo '<div class="pagination" >';

        $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM images");
        $result->execute();
        $row = $result->fetch();
        $total_records = $row[0];
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 10);

        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
            echo "<a href='?page=".$i."'";
            if($page==$i)
            {
                echo "class=active";
            }
                echo ">";
                echo "".$i."</a> ";
        };
        echo '</div>'; 
?>
```

Comment: If you know the current page, you could then for example show only the 5 preceding and following page range (and the first and last page), and only where they are >= 1 and <= $total_pages of course

Comment: Thank's for the comment. Can you provide some example?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this! Here is an example, it might not be a perfect fit, but it is some inspiration: [pagination display 5 pages range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592974/php-pagination-display-5pages-range)